# MS Visual Web Developer 2010 Express won't save state

Tags: vwdexpress

MY VWD 2010 Express has stopped saving state and every time I re-open a project all files are closed.  It worked properly for months, whenever I would open a project all the files that were open when I closed it would re-open.  I tried deleting my .suo file but made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Windows menu select "Reset Window Layout"